# Running console application from a different project

Tags: c#, projects

I have a solution in VS2010. Under the solution, I have my main WPF application, with all the user interface, a couple of libraries, and a console application that I want to run when I click a button in my WPF application. My solution structure is similar to this:

```
- Solution
  - WPF App [this is my startup project]
  - Library
  - Another library
  - Console application
```

Now I have done some hunting around, and I've found people looking for how to reference code and classes, and also a solution to this being that I find the path of the executable, and run it as a new process. However, this requires knowing an absolute path, or even a relative path, and I was wondering if that's the only way I can start an application, even though it's in the same solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes,that is true. You must know the path to the executable, either absolute or relative. But that is no breakdown. Why don't you just put your `WPF` exe and `Console` exe in the same directory or in a subdirectory like in `bin\myconsole.exe`? When creating a new `Process`, just pass the name of the `Console` exe to `Process.Start()` and Windows will find your executable.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyProcessSample
{
class MyProcess
{
    // Opens the Internet Explorer application. 
    void OpenApplication(string myFavoritesPath)
    {
        // Start Internet Explorer. Defaults to the home page.
        Process.Start("IExplore.exe");

        // Display the contents of the favorites folder in the browser.
        Process.Start(myFavoritesPath);
    }

    // Opens urls and .html documents using Internet Explorer. 
    void OpenWithArguments()
    {
        // url's are not considered documents. They can only be opened 
        // by passing them as arguments.
        Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "www.northwindtraders.com");

        // Start a Web page using a browser associated with .html and .asp files.
        Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\\myPath\\myFile.htm");
        Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\\myPath\\myFile.asp");
    }

    // Uses the ProcessStartInfo class to start new processes, 
    // both in a minimized mode. 
    void OpenWithStartInfo()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

        Process.Start(startInfo);

        startInfo.Arguments = "www.northwindtraders.com";

        Process.Start(startInfo);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // Get the path that stores favorite links. 
        string myFavoritesPath =
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Favorites);

        MyProcess myProcess = new MyProcess();

        myProcess.OpenApplication(myFavoritesPath);
        myProcess.OpenWithArguments();
        myProcess.OpenWithStartInfo();
    }
}
}
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx).

Comment: Cheers, I guess I'll follow through with that then. :)